# Complex path integral range setting

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, definite-integrals

For the integration of complex function $f(z)=z^2$, path $C=\cos t+i\sin t : 0\le t\ge\pi$ (upper side of unit circle on complex plane).

What I tried was to separate real and imaginary parts and integrate them.

let $z=x+iy$  than $f(x+iy)=u(x,y)+iv(x,y)$

so, $\int_cf(z)dz =\int_cudx-\int_cvdy+i(\int_cudy+\int_cvdx)$.

and my question is how can i set the integral range of  $\int_cudx$ and $\int_cvdy$?

From the path equation $x=1$ at $t=0$ and $x=-1$ at $t=2\pi$ so $\int_1^{-1} udx$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The definition of the line (or path) integral is
$$\int_C f(z) \, \mathrm{d}z = \int_a^b f(C(t))C'(t) \, \mathrm{d}t.$$
Hence in this case you have to evaluate
$$\int_0^{\pi} (\cos t + i\sin t)^2(-\sin t + i\cos t) \, \mathrm{d}t.$$

EDIT: You can also calculate it as a $2D$ real line integral if you absolutely have to. In that case
$$\int_C u(x,y) \, \mathrm{d}x = \int_0^{\pi} u(\cos t,\sin t)(-\sin t) \, \mathrm{d}t$$
and so on.

Comment: Actually the question is calculate the integration value with ∫cf(z)dz=∫cudx−∫cvdy+i(∫cudy+∫cvdx)  formula and your definition of the line integral formula and prove they mean same.so i have to use ∫cf(z)dz=∫cudx−∫cvdy+i(∫cudy+∫cvdx) first...

Comment: @moonjy1120 I see, does my edit answer that question?

Comment: Yes if what I understand is correct, 2D real lin integral of dy is ∫Cu(x,y)dy=∫π0u(cost,sint)(cost)dt.  It is right?

Comment: @moonjy1120 Yes. By the way, you can also use latex in comments to make it more readable.